# Convert Results of LINQ to SQL Query to XML/JSON

Tags: asp.net, database, linq-to-sql, webforms

I wish to populate a JavaScript array with the results of a database query. From what I understand, a good approach is to populate a bunch of directories on my server with serialized XML or JSON files which my JS functions can then read into without having to access the database. Is this true? Should the database write these XML files upon user interaction, or should they be prepopulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the details you have provided:

I Personally would create a Web Service endpoint returning your linq query serialized to JSON using JSON.NET or an equivalent. The endpoint can then be called using ajax within your client page.

You can check this example out on [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet) for how to create a asmx (legacy) web service. Also you can look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) example of using the [WebMethod] attribute .

A web method in your code behind files.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
public string GetMyQueryResultsAsJson()
{
    var results = GetQueryResults();
    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = jss.Serialize(results);
    return json;
}
```

A ajax call on your client page:

```
function loadData() {
   var myArray = []; 
   $.getJSON("<%= ResolveUrl("~/MyPage.aspx/GetMyQueryResultsAsJson") %>", function (data) {
       $.each(data, function(obj) {
           myArray.push([obj.id, obj.someValue, obj.AnotherValue]);
       });
   });
}
```

Comment: I just finished watching the video you linked. The guy in the video recommends placing the query code in classes separate from the .aspx page. Where do you recommend I place "GetQueryResults()"? In the same code-behind as the WebMethod, or elsewhere?

Comment: Yes thats correct, its good practice to separte your javascript into self contained files. Regarding GetQueryResults() how do you currently retrieve data from your database? Do you have a data access layer?

Comment: I'm currently retrieving data inside <script runat="server"> tags located in my .aspx page.

Comment: ok well if you move that to the code behind, so your page.aspx.cs. Then you can call that method from within the WebMethod

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25870/discussion-between-routemapper-and-gdp)

Answer (score 1):

I used `jQuery ajax` with `generic http handler` returing `json`
I created handler and put my business logic there.
It return me the result in form of `json`
I iterated the `json` using jquery.
And created my html form that.

### Edit 1

Here are some useful links
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203621/Call-HTTPhandler-from-jQuery-Pass-data-and-retriev

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/11/sp2010-ajax-part-4-returning-json-from.html

### Edit 2

You can also take benefit of jtemplate
http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/05/using-the-jtemplate-jquery-plugin-with-ajax-and-asp-net/

http://encosia.com/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Looks like I've got some research cut out for me :)

Comment: I will advise to use `json` rather than `xml`. And `http handler` over `web-service` for jquery call.